# If $f$ is thrice differentiable on $[−1,1]$ such that $f(−1)=0,f(1)=1$ and $f'(0)=0$, then $f'''(c)\ge3$ for some $c\in(−1,1)$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

> $f$ is a three times differentiable function on $[−1,1]$ such that $f(−1)=0, f(1)=1$ and $f'(0)=0$. Using Taylor's theorem show that $f'''(c)\ge3$ for some $c\in(−1,1)$.

How can I proceed with this question?

I applied the taylor's theorem,and got to,

$1=2f'(-1) + 2f''(-1) + (4/3)f'''(c)$

I am not able to proceed further,
Thanks.

Comment: The linked-to "duplicate" has an additional hypothesis, $f(0)=0$, not present here, but there is a (new) exact duplicate at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1949496

Comment: @BarryCipra: That is correct. A closer look at the solution in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/891342/42969 however shows that it still works without the condition that $f(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

This is false.  $f(x) = (1/2) x + 1/2$ is a function that is infinitely differentiable and is such that $f(-1) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$, but $f^{\prime\prime\prime} = 0$.

Comment: but **f'(0)=0** this condition is not satisfied for this function

Comment: @Shivam Gour  The condition that $f^{\prime}(0) = 0$ was not there in your initial post.

Comment: it was there, maybe the improper way of presentation of que from my side did that, sorry for the problem.

Comment: @Shivam Gour  Here is a link to a solution to the problem. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889903/show-that-f3c-ge-3-for-c-in-1-1?rq=1

Comment: @user74973, that linked-to problem has an extra hypothesis, $f(0)=0$.