# Prove that $f'''(x) > 3$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given a function $f: [-1, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be $3$ times differentiable such that $f(-1) = 0;\ f(1)  = 1;\ f'(0) = 0$.

Prove that for some $c$ in $[-1, 1]$, $f'''(c)  \geq 3$.

Comment: Duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1926555/if-f-is-thrice-differentiable-on-%E2%88%921-1-such-that-f%E2%88%921-0-f1-1-and-f0, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889903/show-that-f3c-ge-3-for-c-in-1-1?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @BarryCipra: If you consider $g(x)=f(x)-\frac{x^3+1}{2}$, we have that $g'''(x)=f'''(x)-3$ where $g(x)$ fulfills the simpler constraints $g(-1)=g(1)=g'(0)=0$. If we prove that $g'''(x)\geq 0$ somewhere, the claim readily follows.

Comment: On the other hand, assuming $g'''(x)<0$ for every $x\in(-1,1)$ if follows that $g(-1)\neq g(1)$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, I think this question is actually a duplicate of the first link in StubbornAtom's comment, which is **not** a duplicate of the second link....

Comment: Well, if the first link was incorrectly marked as a duplicate, (One had the requirement f(0)= 0; the other didn't) and that the difference was significant to the answer (did the answer require f(0) = 0?), then the correct thing to do is answer this question correctly as the original did not (and unmark the first as a duplicate and maybe make the older a duplicate of this newer one).  If the difference is not significant, than mark this one as a duplicate of the second.

Comment: It is correct that this question is not an exact duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/889903/42969. A closer look at the solution https://math.stackexchange.com/a/891342/42969 however shows that it still works without the condition $f(0) = 0$.